# how to retrieve specific data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

here I'm using mean stack.this is my database model

```
    var datas = mongoose.model('datas',{
    username: string,
    password: string,
    email: string
});
```

this is my retriving code.

```
app.use('/api/datas',function(req,res) {
    console.log('fetching reviews');
});
```

how can i retrive only username and password for given username feild.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to find in your database one user with username and password sent by your client side ?

You can do that with this way :

```
app.use('/api/datas',function(req,res) {
    var model = mongoose.model('datas');
    model.find(
        {username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password}, // Search request
        {username:1, password:1, email:0}, // You only want to get in return username and password, no email
        function(err, reponse) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err); // On error
            }
            else {
                console.log(response); // Data found
            }
        });
});
```

Hope it helps.